# Does Prokka do six-frame translations?

Tags: sequence-annotation

Does Prokka do six-frame genome annotations? The corresponding publication does not mention it.

> Seemann, Torsten. 2014. “Prokka: Rapid Prokaryotic Genome Annotation.” Bioinformatics  30 (14): 2068–69.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, Prokka will consider all six-frames, the gene prediction is actually done with Prodigal, paper:
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2848648/

github:
https://github.com/hyattpd/Prodigal